# Deserialize throws exception

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to store a List as a BLOB in a sqlite database, but I'm having some trouble reconstructing the List. I'll admit that I dont know much about how the BinaryFormatter or MemoryStream works.

Inserting a row seems to work fine:

```
public void InsertRow()
{
    List<float> myList = new List<float>();
    myList.Add(12);
    myList.Add(13);
    myList.Add(14);
    myList.Add(15);
    myList.Add(16);

    var binFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    var mStream = new MemoryStream();
    binFormatter.Serialize(mStream, myList);

    SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(m_dbConnection);

    byte[] data = mStream.ToArray();

    command.CommandText = "insert into photos (photo) values (@photo)";
    command.Parameters.Add("@photo", DbType.Binary, 237).Value = data;
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

The Deserialize method throws a System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: End of Stream encountered before parsing was completed:

```
public void GetRow()
{
    string sql = "select photo from photos where id = 1";
    SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, m_dbConnection);

    using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            byte[] buffer = GetBytes(reader);

            var mStream = new MemoryStream();
            var binFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();

            mStream.Write(buffer, 0, 237);
            mStream.Position = 0;

            var myObject = binFormatter.Deserialize(mStream) as List<float>;
        }
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? Also, why does the 5 floats in myList result in 237 bytes when serialized?

Edit: Added the GetBytes function:

```
static byte[] GetBytes(SQLiteDataReader reader)
{
    const int CHUNK_SIZE = 2 * 1024;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[CHUNK_SIZE];
    long bytesRead;
    long fieldOffset = 0;
    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        while ((bytesRead = reader.GetBytes(0, fieldOffset, buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
            stream.Write(buffer, 0, (int)bytesRead);
            fieldOffset += bytesRead;
        }
        return stream.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you hardcoding the size of the data? What does the `GetBytes()` method do? As for the why+size: the serialized data contains a lot of metadata information. You can see this yourself if you save the data as a file and open it with a text editor.

Comment: On my machine your code serializes 238 bytes of data, don't hardcode the size, use `mStream.Length`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have hardcoded the size of your serialized data. **Don't do that!**

```
List<float> myList = new List<float>();
myList.Add(12);
myList.Add(13);
myList.Add(14);
myList.Add(15);
myList.Add(16);

var binFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
var mStream = new MemoryStream();
binFormatter.Serialize(mStream, myList);
Console.WriteLine(mStream.Length);
```

This outputs 238, not 237. You've lost one byte which is why you're getting "End of Stream encountered before parsing was completed".

So don't hardcode the size, use all the bytes of the stream. This goes for deserialization as well. And **no**, this does not mean you should be using 238, **hardcoding the expected size is 100% wrong**

This code works:

```
List<float> myList = new List<float>();
myList.Add(12);
myList.Add(13);
myList.Add(14);
myList.Add(15);
myList.Add(16);

var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
var stream1 = new MemoryStream();
formatter.Serialize(stream1, myList);

var array = stream1.ToArray();
Console.WriteLine(array.Length);

var stream2 = new MemoryStream();
stream2.Write(array, 0, array.Length);
stream2.Position = 0;

foreach (var value in formatter.Deserialize(stream2) as List<float>)
    Console.WriteLine(value);
```

and outputs:

```
238
12
13
14
15
16
```

Note that you can construct a `MemoryStream` around an existing byte array and then you don't have to reposition it so the deserialization from my example above can be shortened to:

```
var stream2 = new MemoryStream(array);

foreach (var value in formatter.Deserialize(stream2) as List<float>)
    Console.WriteLine(value);
```

Comment: Thank you! I can't believe I didn't catch that off by one error..  I 100% agree that hard-coding the size is wrong, this was just while experimenting. Thanks again!

Comment: Note, you should *probably* reconsider the decision to use BinaryFormatter and persisting the objects to a database. Versioning problems over time can make old data impossible or very hard to deserialize. You should consider using a format which isn't so tightly coupled to the actual objects as BinaryFormatter is, such as json, xml, or protobuf. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/version-tolerant-serialization for some information on this, but there's plenty of other articles out there on this topic.

Comment: I agree, I decided to convert the List<float> into an array[] instead, storing only the raw data.

Answer (score -1):

```
binFormatter.Serialize(mStream, myList);

mStream.Close();  // to be sure
byte[] data = mStream.ToArray();

command.Parameters.Add("@photo", DbType.Binary).Value = data;  // don't specify (override) the size.
```

Comment: How is this even an answer?. no explanation, OP is saying that he is facing exception during deserialization.

Comment: And exceptions in Deserialization are often caused by errors during Serialization.

Comment: ok, how is closing MemoryStream during Serialization related to Exception during Deserialization?.

Comment: Never call ToArray on an open stream.